# Are there programs or scripts which can clear the clipboard on Mac without a reboot?

Tags: macos, clipboard, finder, recent-file-list

Could one have a script or program for Mac, which would when run, clear the clipboard as well as Finder's "Recent Folders" list in the Go menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this command in a terminal:

```
$ printf '' | pbcopy
```

will clear the clipboard by setting it's contents to an empty string.

<s>For clearing Finder's Recent Folders List, this terminal command seems to work:</s>

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Finder FXRecentFolders {} ;killall Finder
```

Comment: Thank you. FYI, while the clipboard command works, for whatever reason the clipboard window still shows clipboard contents are "text" even though is indeed empty. I also can't get Recent Folders to clear with that command but it's better than what I had found.

Comment: Hmm.  Another one of those 'works for me' type solutions.  I was afraid of that.  Maybe ``sudo killall Finder``?  I'm editing that out of my response, then.